# How does the chain-rule look for the gradient of a loss function?

Tags: loss-functions, gradient-descent, derivative, gradient, word2vec

When we are computing the gradient of the loss function, $L$, of a Word2Vec model, for the context word-embedding, $w_i$, and the target word-embedding, $t$. Where the loss function, $L$, looks like:

$$L(z(w,t)) = -\log(\frac{e^{z_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} e^{z_j}})$$

Does the chain-rule set-up for $\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_i}$ look like:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_i} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial z} \cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial w_i}$$

Or does it look like:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_i} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial z_i} \cdot \frac{\partial z_i}{\partial w_i}$$

And for $\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}$, would it look like:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial z} \cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$$

Or does it look like:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial z_i} \cdot \frac{\partial z_i}{\partial t}$$

The question being, do we specifically use $z_i$, or do we use $z$? Where $z$ is the input to the SoftMax Function. This is important to me because the calculated gradient will be different depending on which is used, that being $z$ or $z_i$.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is $z$ vs $z_i?$

Comment: @Dave Thank you! So $z$ is the dot product between two row vectors, one being a context word-embedding vector in the entire vocabulary, $w$, and the other being the target word-embedding vector, $t$. $z_i$ is a more specific $z$ where it is the dot product between two row vectors again, where one is still the target word-embedding vector, $t$, but now the other row-vector is a specific context word-embedding vector, $w_i$. So $w$ is some word in the vocabulary, and $w_i$ is the word we want. $z_j = z_i$ where $j = i$.

Comment: @Dave Also if you see something fundamentally wrong in my understanding of Word2Vec, please point it out too! If you are familiar with Word2Vec, how would you set-up the chain-rule?